# Enter virtual console for Linux guest OS from inside vSphere

Tags: linux, vmware-vsphere, console, rdesktop

How can I open a Linux virtual console from inside VMware vSphere? I am able to open the console for a Linux guest OS, but when I press e.g. `Ctrl-Alt-F1`, the local machine (which is also running Linux, and from which I access vSphere remotely via `rdesktop`) switches to a virtual console, not the Linux guest OS inside vSphere.

Answer (score 1):

You must first enable the console access, the hotkey is then Alt+F1

> Press Esc until you return to the main direct console screen. If you do not have access to the direct console, you can enable the ESXi Shell from the vSphere Client. Select the host, click the Configuration tab, and click Security Profile in the Software panel.

[VMware KB](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2004746)

Comment: I tried to enable the ESXi Shell from the VSphere Client following this recipe. But when I select the host, I see no tab Configuration. This is for VMware vSphere Client 6.0.0.

Comment: updated the link, you should really just google vmware docs.

Comment: I'm relatively new to VMware and have mistaken accessing the host's direct console (which is apparently what the instruction says) with accessing the VM's console (which is what I tried). Unfortunately I don't have privileges to modify host configurations in this environment. (It's a large VMware setup with many hosts where I own a few Linux VMs.)